# python debug error when quit() in atexit._run_exitfuncs

Tags: python, ubuntu, exit

I installed a package, first using virtual environment and then system wide (well, I think I did that) and now I get this error when I exit (*quit()*) python.

The error appears always, even when doing nothing. With this, I mean that by running python (Python 3.5.1, on Ubuntu 14.04) and then just exiting with *quit()* (and nothing else/before this). With this simple procedure I get the following output:

$ Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
$ PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I started getting this error after the installation of a package, which now I think I didn't installed it correctly (well, maybe it is another thing). The problem is that I can't figure out how to solve this (I already uninstalled and reinstalled the package). Any way of getting more information on the *atexit._run_exitfuncs* error output? Other tip? Thanks in advance!